# How to find character in a String array that exist in all Indexes

Tags: java

I have String of arrays and trying to print out the characters that are common in all indexes along with their frequency.

```
input: String[] str = {"been", "bean", "bread", "boat"};
output: 'b':4
```

I tried it below code but the output

```
public class RepeatedChar {
    public static Map<Character, Integer> repeatedChars(String[] str){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> repeated_char = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> output = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            String temp = str[i];
            for(int j =0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                if(repeated_char.get(temp.charAt(j)) == null) {
                    repeated_char.put(temp.charAt(j), 1); 
                } else {
                    repeated_char.put(temp.charAt(j), repeated_char.get(temp.charAt(j))+1);
                }
            }
            }
       
            for (Character i : repeated_char.keySet()) {
                
                if(repeated_char.get(i) > 1) {
                    if(repeated_char.get(i)>=str.length) {
                        output.put(i, repeated_char.get(i));
                        
                    }
                }
            }
                return output;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] input = {"been", "bean", "bread", "boat"};
    System.out.println(RepeatedChar.repeatedChars(input));
}
}
```

output should be 'b':4 only but it is printing 'e':4 as well.

Comment: `boat` has no `e`, it seems your problem is double-counting `been` (you shouldn't count the same character more than once per string)

Comment: Which can get a little tricky if each word has more than one of any given character.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a set to keep track of the characters present in the current index  you are processing to avoid double counting of a character from the current index.

In you first for loop create a set to track those characters.

```
           for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                String temp = str[i];
                Set<Character> uniqueCharactersInIndex = new HashSet<Character>();
                for(int j =0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                    if(!uniqueCharactersInIndex.contains(temp.charAt(j))) {
                      if(repeated_char.get(temp.charAt(j)) == null) {
                        repeated_char.put(temp.charAt(j), 1); 
                      } else {
                        repeated_char.put(temp.charAt(j), repeated_char.get(temp.charAt(j))+1);
                      }
                      uniqueCharactersInIndex.add(temp.charAt(j));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Note: If the character was already processed for that index you are not doing anything but moving to the next character.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Now the problem is if you add e in the last string, the frequency is coming as 3 for character 'e' but it should be 4.

Comment: I am not seeing that.  Maybe something is off in the overall class or how you add my snippet?  Do you want me to post my entire class?  I just tried with String[] input = {"been", "bean", "bread", "beat"}; and the response is {b=4, e=4}

Comment: Yes with your input string the first index has two e, so technically the frequency for e should be 5.

Comment: Ahh... that was unclear.  I thought you were indicating you only wanted to count characters that were in each element in the array and only count them once.  You want to count characters that are in each element in the array, but for those that qualify show how many times each of those characters appear.

Answer (score 0):

With this exercise, you will need to run the first word only, because if none of the characters from the first word exist in other, then there is none.
Something like this quick draft:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class RepeatedChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {"been", "bean", "bread", "boat"};
        Map<Character, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (char character : str[0].toCharArray()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (!str[i].contains(String.valueOf(character))) {
                    break;
                }
                if (str.length == i+1) {
                    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
                    List.of(str).forEach(word -> List.of(word.split("")).forEach(x -> {
                        if (Objects.equals(x, String.valueOf(character))) {
                            counter.getAndIncrement();
                        }
                    }));
                    result.put(character, counter.get());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```